# Regex for Zip Code

Tags: regex

I want to be able to have a **zipcode** that is either 5 digits **(12345)**, or can be 9 digits with no spaces **(123456789)**, or 10 digits with a hyphen if it has the 9 numbers **(12345-6789)**. What I have below is working for my 1st and 3rd scenarios, but cannot get the second scenario working, was wondering if anyone could help me with any suggestions. Thanks.

```
^\d{5}(?:[-]\d{4})?$
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need a regex. This is small enough and static enough that just hand coding the check seems like it would be better than regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?:\d{5}(?:[-]\d{4})?|\d{9})$
```

You can do it this way using `|`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/31

Answer (score 3):

You came pretty close, just needed to make the hyphen optional with a `?` after it.

```
^\d{5}(?:-?\d{4})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/gB4jR8/1

Answer (score 0):

@miken32  Your regex accepts all zeros(0). like 00000 or 00000-0000.
I have made some changes that starting 3 characters can't be 0s.

```
^(?!0{3})\d{5}(?:-?\d{4})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/om61st/1

Comment: or you can refer this basic regex tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uCHRyK_VMo